# Eclipselink cache coordination on Tomcat cluster

Tags: tomcat, jpa, caching, eclipselink

I have set up a simple Tomcat cluster which works fine using sticky sessions (mod_jk as a load balancer). 2 nodes run on the same box but on different ports  (it is my test environment).
Unfortunately, if I turn off the L2 cache, the performance of the application drops dramaticaly.
In order to enable it, Ive been trying to use rmi approach described [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CacheCoordination).

- I ran **rmiregistry** on its default port.
- I added <distributable /> to web.xml of my app on each node
- I added necessary eclipselink properties to persistence.xml:

  <property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.protocol" value="rmi" />
  <property name="eclipselink.cache.coordination.rmi.url" value="t3://127.0.0.1:1099/" />
  When running this configuration I see the following:
- if I delete an entity on node1, I can see an error message in its catalina.out which says:
  *ERROR org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager- Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
  java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade*
  The entity on node2 does not get deleted from shared cache.
- If I add an entity on node1, nothing happens - neither do I get any error in catalina.out nor the entity adds to the cache of the node2.
  Any hint is deeply appreciated!

Comment: The error doesn't seem related to EclipseLink itself and more to do with your Tomcat clustering and your distributable setting causing it to try to serialize something that isn't serializable.  You might try removing that tag and turn on EclipseLink logging to see what might be happening when the sessions try to connect which occurs at deployment or when the persistence unit is first accessed.

Comment: Removing the distributable tag changed nothing. Also when I turned on eclipselink logging at the finest level, theres only one line in the log:related to the rmi:
Starting Remote Command Manager Service[EclipseLinkCommandChannel, 3b41eba4-b6c4-4bf4-a42e-bc13b61b3e4c, t3://127.0.0.1:1099/]
When I delete an entity, theres no attampt to sync with rmi manager or whatsoever I can trace through the log.

Comment: Focus on startup, as when each server starts up, the RCM will add connections to the JNDI specified in the rmi.url and send out a broadcast to other servers letting them know where to go to connect.  Remote servers must be listening for the broadcast, connect to the JNDI instance to lookup the connection object, and connect in reverse.  Check that each of these things are occurring in your logs before changes start to occur, and if they are not, you may need to specify and open up ports and ensure that all servers can receive broadcasts.

Comment: All nodes are running on the same machine. Do you think there can be problem with the broadcast anyway?

Comment: yes, as they need access to the ports for sending and listening for the broadcasts.  You might also want to try JMS as it is more scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didnt resolve my problem, however I found the workaround.
Wherever the stale cache can cause the trouble, I call a method getCache().evict(<Class name>) of EntityManagerFactory class.
I realize this is not a proper solution but I have no time for further investiation and this one suits my needs.